# How to store select2 remote ajax data after selected laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

I have used select2 for the autocomplete multiselect for my site in laravel the search and select works properly when I hit the form submit the selected values get dissapear and it sends null data to controller why ?

This is my select input

```
<div class="form-group row align-items-center" :class="{'has-danger': errors.has('books'), 'has-success': this.fields.books && this.fields.books.valid }">
    <label for="books" class="col-form-label text-md-right" :class="isFormLocalized ? 'col-md-4' : 'col-md-2'">Books</label>
    <div :class="isFormLocalized ? 'col-md-4' : 'col-md-9 col-xl-8'">
        <select class="itemName form-control" name="books[]" v-model="form.books" placeholder="Select Books" :class="{'form-control-danger': errors.has('books'), 'form-control-success': this.fields.books && this.fields.books.valid}" multiple="multiple">
            <option value='0'>-- Select Books --</option>
        </select>
        <div v-if="errors.has('books')" class="form-control-feedback form-text" v-cloak>@{{ errors.first('books') }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how I am calling ajax and getting result

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        $( ".itemName" ).select2({
            placeholder: 'Select the valid books', 
            ajax: {
                url: '/admin/books/find',
                type: "post",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                        search: params.term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (response) {
                    return {
                        results: response
                    };
                },
                cache: true,
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is how I am saving the datas in my controller

```
$bks = $request->books;
    if($bks == null || $bks = ''){
        $bks = [1];
    }
    else {
        foreach ($bks as $k => $b) {
            $bks[$k] = (int)$b;
        }
    }
    // Storing the rules value as a json / text
    $json = array('orders_limit'=>$request->thrash_limit, 'amount'=>$request->thrash_amount , 'percent'=>$request->thrash_discount, "books"=>$bks);
    $coupon->rules = json_encode($json);
    $coupon->save();
```

Note : The script and ajax I am using to get the data in multiselect is placed on the main file (app.blade.php)
and the form containing file is extending it

Comment: Is the controller getting the other request data e.g. `$request->thrash_limit`? What do you get when you `dd($reequest);` in the controller?

Comment: I get all but I didn't get books